# WordPress: How can get all product of brand from specific a category with WooCommerce Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to print all products of a brand on from category page.

I find the wp_query but I can't print the current brand name of the brand to show all products in this page.

```
// get products
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query'      => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pwb-brand',
          'field'    => 'name',
          'terms'    => array ('NAME?????')
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
} else {
    echo __( 'not found anyhting.' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

For example, i need to get all product of brand name (XXX) that fount in category name (YYY)

Answer (score 0):

This is answer after search :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post','product'),
    'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'terms' => 82,
         'field' => 'id'
       ),
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'brand',
         'terms' => 81,
         'field' => 'id'
       ),
    )
);
query_posts($args);

   if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();         
        the_title();        
    } 
}
```